# Is your username just your email address?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you sign in do you use your email address as your username?

Comment: can you explain it better?

Answer (score 2):

No, your nickname is your login name for the trainer club. If you forgot your nickname you can use your email to retrieve it, but you can't use your email to sign in.